# C# Dapper SQL Server Connection Error : Dapper Connect to anther database not exist in connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I am using Dapper to connect to the SQL server database

My database was SeasonDB, I created anther database called SeasonDb2 to test modifications

it was working well until I removed SeasonDb2 from the SQL server and change the Connection string to SeasonDB

get Connection String  from config file

```
  <connectionStrings>

<add name="SQLServer_Connection" connectionString="data source=.;integrated security=SSPI;initial catalog=SeasonDB"/>
```

when I start the app this error message shown

> 

```
System.Data.DataException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=Error parsing column 1 (DegreeID=1 - Int32)
  Source=Dapper
  StackTrace:
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index, IDataReader reader, Object value) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 3665
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__140`1.MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1102
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 725
   at Season_Models.DataAccess.SQLServerConnector.UsersSearch2(String searchValue) in C:\Users\MohamedSaqr\Source\Repos\PrintAndPublishBranch\SeasonApp\Season Models\DataAccess\SQLServerConnector.cs:line 221
   at Season_Models.GlobalData.GlobalData.get_Users() in C:\Users\MohamedSaqr\Source\Repos\PrintAndPublishBranch\SeasonApp\Season Models\GlobalData\GlobalData.cs:line 149
   at Season_Application.UI.Login.UserLogin() in C:\Users\MohamedSaqr\Source\Repos\PrintAndPublishBranch\SeasonApp\Season Application\UI\Login.cs:line 100
   at Season_Application.UI.Login.SaveOnEnterKeyPressed(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) in C:\Users\MohamedSaqr\Source\Repos\PrintAndPublishBranch\SeasonApp\Season Application\UI\Login.cs:line 170
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Season_Application.Program.Main() in C:\Users\MohamedSaqr\Source\Repos\PrintAndPublishBranch\SeasonApp\Season Application\Program.cs:line 36
Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: Invalid object name 'SeasonDB2.dbo.TableLastModificationTime'.
```

The Running code

```
 public List<UserModel> UsersSearch2(string searchValue)
    {
        List<UserModel> users;
        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer_Connection"].ToString()))
        {
            var p = new DynamicParameters();
            p.Add("@SearchValue", searchValue);

            users =
                connection.Query<UserModel>("SPGetUsers2", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
            foreach (var user in users)
                user.UserDegree = GlobalData.GlobalData.Degrees
                    .Where(degree => degree.DegreeID == user.DegreeID).ToList()[0];
        }

        return users;
    }
```

the Error Show Here

```
                users =
                connection.Query<UserModel>("SPGetUsers2", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

the problem that dapper connect to SeasonDb2

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'SeasonDB2.dbo.TableLastModificationTime'.

My stored Procedure use SeasonDB

```
USE [SeasonDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SPTableLastModificationTime]    
Script Date: 25/11/2020 02:43:32 م ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- Batch submitted through debugger: 
SQLQuery1.sql|7|0|C:\Users\Navy5\AppData\Local\Temp\~vs5FCC.sql

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPTableLastModificationTime]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@TableName sysname,
@TableLastModificationTime DateTime output
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
Select  @TableLastModificationTime =  [TableLastModiticationTime]
    FROM [SeasonDB2].[dbo].[TableLastModificationTime]
    Where TableName = @TableName

    if @TableLastModificationTime is null
    Begin
         select @TableLastModificationTime = 
        ius.last_user_update
        FROM
        sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ius INNER JOIN
        sys.tables tbl ON (tbl.OBJECT_ID = ius.OBJECT_ID)
        WHERE ius.database_id = DB_ID() and tbl.name  = @TableName


        if @TableLastModificationTime is null
        Begin
            select @TableLastModificationTime = GETDATE()
        END


        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableLastModificationTime]
        ([TableName],TableLastModiticationTime)
        VALUES
        (@TableName,@TableLastModificationTime)


    END
    Else
    Begin
        Declare @TempTime DATETIME


        SELECT @TempTime =  ius.last_user_update
        FROM
        sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ius INNER JOIN
        sys.tables tbl ON (tbl.OBJECT_ID = ius.OBJECT_ID)
        WHERE ius.database_id = DB_ID() and tbl.name  = @TableName

        IF @TempTime is not null AND @TempTime <> @TableLastModificationTime
        BEGIN
            SET @TableLastModificationTime = @TempTime

            UPDATE [dbo].[TableLastModificationTime]
            SET 
              [TableLastModiticationTime] = @TableLastModificationTime,
              EditLastTime = GetDate()
            WHERE [TableName] = @TableName
        END

        


    END
        
END
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems that the stored procedure code still references SeasonDB2. Check the code in your store procedure

Comment: Stored Procedure use SeasonDB

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the stored procedure. More precisely, here:

```
Select  @TableLastModificationTime =  [TableLastModiticationTime]
    FROM [SeasonDB2].[dbo].[TableLastModificationTime] ...
```

**SeasonDB2** is hardcoded on the query.

You need to alter your SP and remove it since as long as the stored procedure is located on the correct DB this prefix is not required